# Hotchocolate custom filter operation

Tags: hotchocolate

I am trying to create a custom filter operation to do bitwise and operation.
I got stuck on creating the custom FieldHandler, I am really confused about the FilterVisitorContext and how to implement the TryHandleLeave.
I was trying it out with this resource: https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/blob/main/website/src/docs/hotchocolate/v11/api-reference/extending-filtering.md .
Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.